# Implementing a custom async task type and await

Tags: c++, async-await

I am developing a C++ app in which i need to receive messages from an MQ and then parsing them according to their type and for a particular reason I want to make this process (receiving a single message followed by processing it) asynchronous. Since, I want to keep things as simple as possible in a way that the next developer would have no problem continuing the code, I have written a very small class to implement Asynchrony.

I first raise a new thread and pass a function to the thread:

```
task = new thread([&] {
   result = fn();
    isCompleted = true;
});
task->detach();
```

and in order to await the task I do the following:

```
while (!isCompleted && !(*cancelationToken))
{
    Sleep(5);
}
state = 1; // marking the task as completed
```

So far there is no problem and I have not faced any bug or error but I am not sure if this is "a good way to do this" and my question is focused on determining this.

Comment: There is a simple rule of thumb. Do you see a call to `sleep` in the code? Then this is not a good way to do this.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. This functionality already exists in the standard library.

Comment: @super: What if I want to cancel the task?

Comment: "What if I want to cancel the task?" Then you need to add a cancellation mechanism to the task itself. It doesn't matter whether you use your homegrown tasks or the standard library, the mechanism need not be different between the two.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder I don't think there's anything stopping you from doing that. However you implement it, being able to cancel the task relies on the worker thread periodically checking for a cancel signal. It's the part of the async task that you implement in other words. Using a robust and tested standard solution will not make it any harder to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: Ok, fine, but you did not answer my question!

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Looks like a perfectly good answer to me. What other kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: In my solution I can also cancel the task, but this approach does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

If your task runs in another core or processor, the variable `isCompleted` may become un-synchronized having two copies in core cache. So you may be waiting more than needed.

If you have to wait for something it is better to use a [semaphore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore).

As said in comments, using standard methods is better anyway.